# How do I make my CSS code responsive to small screens?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have tried a number of things based upon reading online tutorials and nothing seems to be changing the layout of my webpages for small screens.  I thought that by changing my .sidebar and .card to be width 100% they would stack instead of shrinking and appearing next to each other when I resize the browser.  I also tried a flex display column but that didn't work either.  This is my first big project and I am trying to find the answer for myself but am really struggling...

I added a media query for smaller screens because that appears to be where everything is warped.   In the blogpost.html page I tried making the .card and .sidebar width 100% and max-width 100%.  I tried making the grid-column-areas 100%.  I thought I would be stacking things on top of each other but nothing seems to be changing the layout at all.  I tried a few other things that I can't even remember at this point...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<hmtl lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/073f6e732c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/blogpoststyle.css">
        <title>Simple & Seasonal September Blog Post</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="header"><h1>Simple & Seasonal</h1></div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <a class="home" href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a class="active" href="blog">Blog</a>
            <a href="recipes">Recipes</a>
            <a href="contact">Contact</a>
            <a href="subscribe.html">Subscribe</a>
        </div>

       <!--SIDEBAR-->

        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="avatar"><img src="resources/images/IMG_9612.jpg"></div>
            <div class="profile"><span>About Me</span>
                <p>Hi!  I'm <b>Suzanne</b>, a <u>teacher</u>, <u>wife</u> and part-time <u>blogger</u>.  I love visiting farmers markets and finding in-season produce to use in my recipes.  Feel free to <a class="subscribe" href="subscribe.html"><em>subscribe</em></a> for more recipes.  You can also follow me here:</p><br>
                <i id="small" class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
                <i id="small" class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
                <i id="small" class="fa-brands fa-pinterest"></i>
                <i id="small" class="fa-brands fa-square-instagram"></i>
                <br><span>Bon Appetit</span></div>
        </div>

       <!--BLOG POST CARD-->

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <img src="resources/images/pierpaolo-riondato-s7r4xjKXo0s-unsplash.jpg" alt="basket of red apples" class="card-image" width="600">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
            <span>Apples</span>
            <h4>What to make with apples this fall</h4>
            <blockquote cite="https://www.stylecraze.com/articles/slogans-on-healthy-food/">
                An apple a day keeps the doctor away - Proverb
            </blockquote>
            <p>Apples are abundant this time of year.  Here are some of my favorite ways to use them: in salads with roasted vegetables, leafy greens, and cheese, baked with oats and spices for a delicious healthy dessert, and cooked with squash and then blended into a nourishing soup.</p>
            <br>
            <p>My husband an I went apple picking recently and picked up a couple of bushels of Cortland apples, which means I have been looking for creative ways to use them this fall.  If you aren't familiar with them, Cortland apples are juicy and slightly tart, with a bright red skin and snowy white flesh.  They are a terrific baking apple: Great for pies, cobblers, and crisps.  When sliced, Cortlands are excellent for salads and cheese plates, as the flesh doesn't brown and discolor quickly.</p>
            <br>
            <p>Here are three fabulous recipes to try during apple season:</p>
            <figure>
            <img src="https://thrivinghomeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Autumn-Chopped-Salad-5-730x487.jpg" alt="apple-salad" class="recipe-image">
            <figcaption class="figcaption">Autumn Apple Salad with a Maple Viniagrette</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <div class="button"><a href="#" class="button">View Recipe</a></div>
            <figure>
            <img src="https://cookieandkate.com/images/2014/11/gluten-free-apple-crisp-4-768x1151.jpg" alt="apple-crisp" class="recipe-image">
            <figcaption class="figcaption">Gluten Free Apple Crisp</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <div class="button"><a href="#" class="button">View Recipe</a></div>
            <figure>
            <img src="https://www.wellplated.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Butternut-Squash-Apple-Soup.-A-healthy-and-easy-butternut-squash-soup-recipe.-Perfect-for-freezing-and-reheating.jpg" alt="butternut squash apple soup" class="recipe-image">
            <figcaption class="figcaption">Butternut Squash Apple Soup</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <div class="button"><a href="#" class="button">View Recipe</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--FOOTER-->
        
        <div class="footer">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
                <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
                <i class="fa-brands fa-pinterest"></i>
                <i class="fa-brands fa-square-instagram"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</hmtl>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@400;700&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,100;1,700&display=swap');

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: #e9f0ce;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, #e9f0ce, #e5ecca, #e1e8c6, #dde4c3, #d9e0bf, #d1d9b4, #c9d1a9, #c1ca9e, #b3be89, #a6b275, #98a660, #8b9a4c);
  color: #3b3f20;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  gap: 1rem;
  }

/*grid display items*/

.sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}

.card {
    grid-area: content;
    background-color: white;
    color:#3b3f20; 
    border-radius: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
      }

.card-body {
        padding: 1rem;
      }
/*HEADER AND NAVBAR*/

.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-area: header;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
    grid-area: navbar;
    background-color: #3b3f20;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

.navbar a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color:#3b3f20;
}

.navbar a.active {
    background-color: white;
    color: #3b3f20;
}
/*FOOTER*/

.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2rem;
    padding: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
      }

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header header header"
        "navbar navbar navbar"
        "sidebar content content"
        "blank   content content"
        "footer footer footer";
    color: #444;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    margin: 5rem;
    }

/*text*/
    h1 {
        color: #d45464;
        font-size: 5rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: Amatic SC;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        padding-top: 2rem;
        text-align: center;
      }
    
      .fa-brands {
        font-size: 30px;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #3b3f20;
      }
    
      .fa-brands:hover {
        opacity: .7;
      }

      span {
        color: #d45464;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        font-family: Amatic SC;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
      }
    
      h4 {
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: Roboto;
      }
    
      p {
        padding: 4px;
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      .figcaption {
        font-family: Amatic SC;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
      }

      .profile {
        font-family: Open Sans;
        padding: 2rem 2rem 4rem 2rem;
      }
    
      .subscribe {
        color: #d45464;
      }

      blockquote {
        color: #d45464;
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      /*images*/

      img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        border-top-left-radius: 12px;
        border-top-right-radius: 12px;
        height: 20rem;
        object-fit: cover;
        text-align: center;
      }

      .avatar img {
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 1rem auto 0 auto;
        object-fit: cover;
        width: 80%;
        height: 300px;
      }

      .recipe-image {
        display: block;
        border-radius: 12px;
        height: 25rem;
        width: 50%;
        object-fit: cover;
        margin: 4rem auto 0 auto;
      }

      #small {
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        color: #3b3f20;
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 0;
        width: auto;

      }

      /* button */

      .button   {
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 100px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: none;
        margin: auto;
        background-color: #d45464;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: Open Sans;
        padding: 2px;
      }

      /* Responsive */
@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 600px) {


  nav {
    margin: 0;
  }

  img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .sidebar {
    width: 100%; 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .card {
    width: 100%; 
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better if you add an `order` in the `card` and `footer` or `blog post`, so that the layout of the card is neater, making it one column

[check this video](https://www.loom.com/share/f2ad80b9c84f45d7a1bf8cda54dd4b7a)

and if you want to know more about the order you can read here

[W3School-order](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.php)
[MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

```css
   @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@400;700&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,100;1,700&display=swap");

    html {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }

    body {
      display: grid;
      place-items: center;
      background-color: #e9f0ce;
      background-image: linear-gradient(
        to right top,
        #e9f0ce,
        #e5ecca,
        #e1e8c6,
        #dde4c3,
        #d9e0bf,
        #d1d9b4,
        #c9d1a9,
        #c1ca9e,
        #b3be89,
        #a6b275,
        #98a660,
        #8b9a4c
      );
      color: #3b3f20;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0 auto;
      gap: 1rem;
    }

    /*grid display items*/

    .sidebar {
      grid-area: sidebar;
      background-color: white;
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 12px;
      text-align: center;
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
    }

    .card {
      grid-area: content;
      background-color: white;
      color: #3b3f20;
      border-radius: 12px;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-align: center;
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
    }

    .card-body {
      padding: 1rem;
    }
    /*HEADER AND NAVBAR*/

    .header {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      grid-area: header;
      margin: auto;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .navbar {
      grid-area: navbar;
      background-color: #3b3f20;
      margin: auto;
      font-family: Open Sans;
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
      border-radius: 12px;
    }

    .navbar a {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      font-size: 18px;
      border-radius: 12px;
    }

    .navbar a:hover {
      background-color: white;
      color: #3b3f20;
    }

    .navbar a.active {
      background-color: white;
      color: #3b3f20;
    }
    /*FOOTER*/

    .footer {
      grid-area: footer;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 60px;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 2rem;
      padding: 2rem;
      padding-bottom: 5rem;
    }

    .grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
      grid-template-areas:
        "header header header"
        "navbar navbar navbar"
        "sidebar content content"
        "blank   content content"
        "footer footer footer";
      color: #444;
      grid-gap: 1em;
      margin: 5rem;
    }

    /*text*/
    h1 {
      color: #d45464;
      font-size: 5rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-family: Amatic SC;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      padding-top: 2rem;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .fa-brands {
      font-size: 30px;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #3b3f20;
    }

    .fa-brands:hover {
      opacity: 0.7;
    }

    span {
      color: #d45464;
      font-size: 2.5rem;
      font-family: Amatic SC;
      font-weight: bold;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
    }

    h4 {
      padding: 5px;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: Roboto;
    }

    p {
      padding: 4px;
      font-family: Roboto;
    }

    .figcaption {
      font-family: Amatic SC;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
      padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
    }

    .profile {
      font-family: Open Sans;
      padding: 2rem 2rem 4rem 2rem;
    }

    .subscribe {
      color: #d45464;
    }

    blockquote {
      color: #d45464;
      font-family: Roboto;
    }

    /*images*/

    img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      border-top-left-radius: 12px;
      border-top-right-radius: 12px;
      height: 20rem;
      object-fit: cover;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .avatar img {
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 1rem auto 0 auto;
      object-fit: cover;
      width: 80%;
      height: 300px;
    }

    .recipe-image {
      display: block;
      border-radius: 12px;
      height: 25rem;
      width: 50%;
      object-fit: cover;
      margin: 4rem auto 0 auto;
    }

    #small {
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      color: #3b3f20;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 0;
      width: auto;
    }

    /* button */

    .button {
      display: inline-block;
      text-decoration: none;
      width: 100px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: none;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: #d45464;
      color: white;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: Open Sans;
      padding: 2px;
    }

    /* Responsive */
    @media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 600px) {
      nav {
        margin: 0;
      }

      img {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
      }

      .sidebar {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 0;
      }
      /* add order */
      .card {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 0;
        order: 1;
      }
      
      .grid{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .footer{
        order: 3;
      }
    }
```

```html
<body>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="header"><h1>Simple & Seasonal</h1></div>
        <div class="navbar">
          <a class="home" href="index.html">Home</a>
          <a class="active" href="blog">Blog</a>
          <a href="recipes">Recipes</a>
          <a href="contact">Contact</a>
          <a href="subscribe.html">Subscribe</a>
        </div>

        <!--SIDEBAR-->

        <div class="sidebar">
          <div class="avatar"><img src="resources/images/IMG_9612.jpg" /></div>
          <div class="profile">
            <span>About Me</span>
            <p>
              Hi! I'm <b>Suzanne</b>, a <u>teacher</u>, <u>wife</u> and
              part-time <u>blogger</u>. I love visiting farmers markets and
              finding in-season produce to use in my recipes. Feel free to
              <a class="subscribe" href="subscribe.html"><em>subscribe</em></a>
              for more recipes. You can also follow me here:
            </p>
            <br />
            <i id="small" class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
            <i id="small" class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
            <i id="small" class="fa-brands fa-pinterest"></i>
            <i id="small" class="fa-brands fa-square-instagram"></i>
            <br /><span>Bon Appetit</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--BLOG POST CARD-->

        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <img
              src="resources/images/pierpaolo-riondato-s7r4xjKXo0s-unsplash.jpg"
              alt="basket of red apples"
              class="card-image"
              width="600"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <span>Apples</span>
            <h4>What to make with apples this fall</h4>
            <blockquote
              cite="https://www.stylecraze.com/articles/slogans-on-healthy-food/"
            >
              An apple a day keeps the doctor away - Proverb
            </blockquote>
            <p>
              Apples are abundant this time of year. Here are some of my
              favorite ways to use them: in salads with roasted vegetables,
              leafy greens, and cheese, baked with oats and spices for a
              delicious healthy dessert, and cooked with squash and then blended
              into a nourishing soup.
            </p>
            <br />
            <p>
              My husband an I went apple picking recently and picked up a couple
              of bushels of Cortland apples, which means I have been looking for
              creative ways to use them this fall. If you aren't familiar with
              them, Cortland apples are juicy and slightly tart, with a bright
              red skin and snowy white flesh. They are a terrific baking apple:
              Great for pies, cobblers, and crisps. When sliced, Cortlands are
              excellent for salads and cheese plates, as the flesh doesn't brown
              and discolor quickly.
            </p>
            <br />
            <p>Here are three fabulous recipes to try during apple season:</p>
            <figure>
              <img
                src="https://thrivinghomeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Autumn-Chopped-Salad-5-730x487.jpg"
                alt="apple-salad"
                class="recipe-image"
              />
              <figcaption class="figcaption">
                Autumn Apple Salad with a Maple Viniagrette
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <div class="button"><a href="#" class="button">View Recipe</a></div>
            <figure>
              <img
                src="https://cookieandkate.com/images/2014/11/gluten-free-apple-crisp-4-768x1151.jpg"
                alt="apple-crisp"
                class="recipe-image"
              />
              <figcaption class="figcaption">
                Gluten Free Apple Crisp
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <div class="button"><a href="#" class="button">View Recipe</a></div>
            <figure>
              <img
                src="https://www.wellplated.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Butternut-Squash-Apple-Soup.-A-healthy-and-easy-butternut-squash-soup-recipe.-Perfect-for-freezing-and-reheating.jpg"
                alt="butternut squash apple soup"
                class="recipe-image"
              />
              <figcaption class="figcaption">
                Butternut Squash Apple Soup
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
            <div class="button"><a href="#" class="button">View Recipe</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--FOOTER-->

        <div class="footer">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
          <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
          <i class="fa-brands fa-pinterest"></i>
          <i class="fa-brands fa-square-instagram"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with this!  it is exactly what I have been trying to do ...!

Comment: if you feel my answer helps you, please accept my answer so that others can also be helped